# Android development: Installed all drivers, but still shows up as AVD Device not found

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, device

I have been using my Motorola Atrix to debug my android applications, but today it shows up as AVD Device not found. I have debugging mode enabled, and I have installed all of the necessary drivers. On my phone it says USB debugging connected.

Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this, but I installed this: http://pdanet.co/ on both my Desktop and android device and  had no trouble finding my device after that. There should be documentation on how to install it on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I found sometimes unplugging/plugging USB cable fixes this problem.